# mongodb function from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

I use mongomapper with mongodb for rails models.
In the mongodb I have this function

```
db.system.js.save({_id:'resumenTemporada',value:function(collection, condition){
    var res=
    db[collection].group({     
        key:{},
        reduce:function(obj,prev){      
            prev.ppa += obj.precipitation;  
            if( obj.temperature < 5 && obj.temperature >0) prev.hf += obj.temperature/4;
        },
        initial : {ppa:0,hf:0},               
        cond: condition});     
    return res ;
    } 
});
```

And get this output

```
> db.eval("return resumenTemporada('stations',{nombre:'pua',fecha:{$gt:'2011-01-01'}});")
[
        {
                "ppa" : 241.19999999999982,
                "hf" : 743.2295249999986
        }
]
```

Ok, how I can call this function from rails ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
results = MongoMapper.database.eval('resumenTemporada', 'stations',{nombre:'pua',fecha:{$gt:'2011-01-01'}})
```

More examples here: https://gist.github.com/307753

Comment: result = MongoMapper.database.eval("return resumenTemporada('stations',{nombre:'pua',fecha:{$gt:'2011-01-01'}});")